# SOQL to get Permission Set Ids for a specific profile Name users

Tags: soql, query

I'm trying to export all permissionset Ids for all users of a specific profile name.

But its giving 0 records.

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Assignee.Name, p.Assignee.Profile.Name, p.PermissionSet.Label, p.AssigneeId, p.PermissionSetId
FROM PermissionSetAssignment p
WHERE p.Permissionset.Name='set' AND p.Assignee.Profile.Name = 'User'
ORDER BY p.AssigneeId, p.PermissionSetId
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your profile name, there is a space before the U?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an inner-join sub-select as follows:

```
SELECT PermissionSetId, AssigneeId
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'Something'
AND AssigneeId IN (
    SELECT Id FROM User
    WHERE Profile.Name = 'Example'
)
```

Comment: How can I also further filter based on the Permission Set Name.

Comment: Add a WHERE clause `PermissionSet.Name = 'Something'`